# Orika - map two fields only if third field matches a string

Tags: java, mapping, orika

I have two fields that I want to map using Orika

```
 @Override
    public void configure(MapperFactory factory) {
        factory.classMap(ClazzA.class, ClazzB.class)
                .byDefault()
                .field("name", "sname")
                .register();
```

*I want to map that field name to the value from sname only if a third field "type" in ClazzB matches a string "stk".*

Is it possible using Orika?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Simply add a custom mapper after regular field mapping.

```
    factory.classMap(ClazzA.class, ClazzB.class)
                .field("name", "sname")
                .byDefault()
                .customize(new CustomMapper<ClazzA, ClazzB>() {
                    @Override
                    public void mapBtoA(ClazzB clazzB, ClazzA clazzA, MappingContext context) {
                        if ("stk".equals(clazzB.getType())) {
                            clazzA.setName(clazzB.getSName());
                        }
                    }                   
                }
                .register();
```

Answer (score 0):

As described in the official Orika documentation [https://orika-mapper.github.io/orika-docs/advanced-mappings.html]
You can add custom field mapping as follow

```
mapperFactory.classMap(Source.class, Destination.class)
    .byDefault()
    .customize(
       new CustomMapper<Source, Destination> {
          public void mapAtoB(A a, B b, MappingContext context) {
             // add your custom mapping code here
          }
       }
    .register();
```